# Creating a NSDictionary from a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I admit im new to the world of coding. For about a week now I have been making a small app by watching guides and doing tutorials, (I have learned a ton of stuff and I actually like this a lot).

I have run into one problem that after looking cant find an answer to at my level. I got a `NSMutableArray` called Appetizers which is the name of my entity. In this entity I have an attribute called "name" amongst others. I want to sort the user inputted data alphabetically on the `tableview`, (it currently shows it in non-alphabetical, order it was put in).

One of the posts I saw was one posted on this site: [UITableView grouping sections from NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397370/uitableview-grouping-sections-from-nsmutablearray). I fell this is what I need but I cant figure out what I have to switch out for my info.

I tried to manually write everything in so I could see the hints but I got errors all over. I saw this post aswell http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/ and when I tried to do the first part where I add info under the @interface I got errors on those lines, (I did change animals to Appetizers). But the picture on the 2nd link is what I want. Alphabetical and the letter in the section header, (if there isn't an entry in that letter then it doesn't show that section). So im in a small bind now. Hope I can get some help. Thanks.

I currently have this running under my @implementation on my `tableviewcontroller`:

```
@synthesize Appetizers;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Appetizers"];
Appetizers = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a NSSortDescriptor to your NSFetchRequest like so :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[fetchRequest]];
```

Comment: Im assuming I add this between Appetizers = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy]; and [self.tableView reloadData];. When I did this I get an error for request, says use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: Add it just before between NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Appetizers"]; and Appetizers = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

Comment: I had tried it there after I made my comment but I still get that error with "request". Error message says "Use of undeclared identifier 'request'.